# Incoming Slack Webhook URL Components

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

Incoming Slack Webhook URL looks like https://hooks.slack.com/services/aaaaa/bbbbb/ccccc -- What is aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc.. Can you please let us know is it possible to find what is the Slack Channel name and workspace name based on this webhook

Comment: The team ID comes right after `/services/`. I don't think the channel ID is included in the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the incoming webhook alone (as a string) it's not possible, apart from the `team_id` mentioned in the comment above.

From my experience with only incoming-webhooks enabled and publicly distributed apps that **information is available only in response after user installs the app with the standard OAuth process**. Keep in mind that reponse will change depending of the scope of your application but if you ask for `incoming-webhook` you will get `channel` together with `url` which is incoming-webhook url. You will also get `team_name` and `team_id` which is Workspace info. You can find detailed explanation at https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#incoming_webhooks_programmatic and https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2.

And here is an example of OAuth response json.

```
{
"ok": true,
"access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
"scope": "identify,bot,commands,incoming-webhook,chat:write:bot",
"user_id": "XXXXXXXX",
"team_name": "Your Workspace Name",
"team_id": "XXXXXXXX",
"incoming_webhook": {
    "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
    "channel_id": "C05002EAE",
    "configuration_url": "https://workspacename.slack.com/services/BXXXXX",
    "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

So in the nutshell, as far as I know, there is no way to get information from webhook alone, but one other option, which is not directly the answer to the question is to expand your application and include web api permissions and then there is nothing stopping you to request that information independently from incoming-webhook directly from the workspace.